# PHP force str_replace to replace only one of results

Tags: php, arrays, string, foreach, str-replace

This is working perfectly :

```
$replaceLyrics=str_replace
(
    'story',
    '_____',
    'The story of my life I take her home I drive all night to keep her warm and time Is frozen (the story of, the story of)'
);

echo $replaceLyrics;
```

output :

```
The _____ of my life I take her home I drive all night to keep her warm and time Is frozen (the _____ of, the _____ of)
```

My question is if it's possible to use internal php funtion to replace only the first occurrence from matches and not all of them.

I'm expecting to get this output :

```
The _____ of my life I take her home I drive all night to keep her warm and time Is frozen (the story of, the story of)
```

Comment: The best thing would be to use preg_match function along with preg_replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done using preg_replace.

```
<?
$str = 'story story story';
echo preg_replace('/story/', '___', $str, 1);
```